# Spring - @scheduled methods in concrete classes not running

Tags: java, spring, task, inversion-of-control, scheduling

I'm relatively new to Spring and I'm trying to run a series of @Scheduled methods in the background regularly.

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractTaskClass {

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someInst;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=10000)
    protected abstract void execute();

    protected SomeClass getSomeInst() {
        return someInst;
    }

}
```

And multiple concrete classes, like this as an example:

```
@Component
public class ConcreteTaskClass extends AbstractTaskClass {

   @Override
   protected void execute() {
      // do stuff ...
   }

}
```

And my application configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.foo.tasks")
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

where com.foo.tasks contains the abstract class above and all the concrete implementation classes.

Spring doesn't seem to be executing my scheduled methods on all the concrete classes. What have I overlooked here? I suppose that since I'm new to Spring it's possible I'm missing something fundamental about how the framework and IoC container works.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but my immediate question is what happens if you put the `@Scheduled` annotation on the concrete classes instead of the abstract class?

Comment: Wow....it works. I can't believe I overlooked that. So I must declare that @Scheduled in all the concrete classes? Seems like a big violation of DRY

Comment: I'm sure you can do something smarter, without really thinking about it, I suspect the issue is because the class is abstract. What about having one concrete class with the annotation, which gets a `List<SomeType>` injected. SomeType implements an interface with an `execute()` method, and your method with the annotation iterates over the list, calling the `execute()` method on the injected classes. Hope that makes sense, I haven't thought it through, but I'd start with something like that.

Comment: The `@Scheduled` annotation is, deliberatly, not `@Inherited` hence you need to put in on the actual method that you need/want to schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment above, a slightly better formatted example of what I'm suggesting. I haven't tested this, so it might take a little experimentation to get it working, but...

```
public interface Task {
  void execute();
}

@Component // Not certain if this is the right annotation...
public class BaseTaskClass {
  @Autowired
  private List<Task> someTasks;

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay=10000)
  public void execute() {
    for (task : someTasks) {
      task.execute();
    }
  }
}

@Component
public class ConcreteTaskClass implements Task {
   @Override
   public void execute() {
     // do stuff ...
   }
}
```